# Pandas replace method not working on column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Pretty simple code. The program seems to completely ignore the replace line. I am looking to move the values of 0, 5, 6 to the value '4' (Assign all elements with values as 0 or 5 or 6 as a 4). This is the column info. I have tried removing "value" and even "inplace" (I know, that gives a new object, however, even then nothing happens and it remains the same)

```
2    14030 
1    10585
3     4917
5      280
4      123
6       51
0       14
Name: EDUCATION, dtype: int64


import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('UCI_Credit_Card.csv')
graph = data[['LIMIT_BAL','AGE']].describe()
data['EDUCATION'].replace(['0', '5', '6'], value='4', inplace=True)
print(data['EDUCATION'].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the `regex` on

```
data['EDUCATION'] = data['EDUCATION'].astype(str).replace(['0', '5', '6'], value='4', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, assuming all of the values are integers.
I have recreated your dataframe and put a replace method

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,3,5,4,6,0],[14030,10585,4917,280,123,51,14]])
df = df.T
print(df)
df.replace([0,5,6],0)
```

Comment: Please accept this as a solution if this works. Let me know if it did not work as you intended.

Comment: My friend, this is not the data frame. This is just a column from it. Might want to give the question another look.

Comment: Sure @AbhishekRai, if this is a public available csv file, could you provide the link ? I can load it up and check ? is this from kaggle ?